# Validation rule based on user profile

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule, user-profile

I'm trying to create a validation rule that accomplishes the following:

I have 2 profiles, profile#1 has a page layout with a field (checkbox) that comes "checked" by default.

For profile#2 I created the same page layout but took off the checkbox field (checkbox field is only relevant for Profile#1, in fact everyone at profile#1 needs to check that field, that is why its mandatory).

I tried playing this out by only assigning different page layouts, but every record (regardless if created by profile#1 or profile#2) is being "check marked" on that box. I need a validation rule that somehow requires the profile#1 to check it, but not profile#2, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: Whenever a requirement that has profile dependencies comes along, I usually consider hierarchy custom settings first. Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure a validation rule is what you need. It sounds like for profile 1 the box should always be checked and for profile 2 it should never be checked. For something like that you want to set the default value to **unchecked**.

Once you do that, you can remove the checkbox from the layout altogether and create a workflow/process to automatically check the box if the user has profile one. For profile 2, just don't do anything. This way, you save profile 1 users some effort (as they no longer have to check it manually) and enforce your data policies.

[image: Step 1]

**Bonus:** Naming conventions for processes vary person to person but it seems most people prefer a detailed name to help emphasize what the process is doing so name your process something like **Campsite Field Update: Checkbox Name** where Campsite is the name of the object and Checkbox Name is the field. Make sure to add detailed descriptions as well. If you use a ticketing system adding the ticket number to the description may also help provide context.

Then select your object, in this case I'm using campsite as it's a bogus object. Select whether it should happen on create or create AND edit. (if profile 2 creates the record, it will be false, but when profile 1 edits the record, should it be set to true or stay false?).

[image: Step 2]

Use the following formula as a guide for your criteria.

[image: Step 3]

Then, just create an action to set the value of the field.

Comment: `$Profile.Name = 'Profile1'` is better, no ids

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the checkbox, mark this as **unchecked**.

Validation rule logic will be like this to show error message.

```
$Profile.Name == 'Profile1' && Checkbox__c == false
```